# Clang producing a symbol lookup error

Tags: clang, llvm

i am getting this error whenever i run clang even with the --version flag

```
clang: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libclang-cpp.so.14: undefined symbol: _ZN4llvm9MDBuilder25createRTTIPointerPrologueEPNS_8ConstantES2_, version LLVM_14
```

pacman -Qi llvm

```
Name            : llvm
Version         : 14.0.6-3
Description     : Compiler infrastructure
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : https://llvm.org/
Licenses        : custom:Apache 2.0 with LLVM Exception
Groups          : None
Provides        : None
Depends On      : llvm-libs  perl
Optional Deps   : None
Required By     : None
Optional For    : clang
Conflicts With  : None
Replaces        : None
Installed Size  : 368.51 MiB
Packager        : Evangelos Foutras <foutrelis@archlinux.org>
Build Date      : Thu 04 Aug 2022 02:34:13 AM WAT
Install Date    : Mon 15 Aug 2022 09:49:26 AM WAT
Install Reason  : Installed as a dependency for another package
Install Script  : No
Validated By    : Signature
```

pacman -Qi clang

```
Name            : clang
Version         : 14.0.6-2
Description     : C language family frontend for LLVM
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : https://clang.llvm.org/
Licenses        : custom:Apache 2.0 with LLVM Exception
Groups          : None
Provides        : clang-analyzer=14.0.6  clang-tools-extra=14.0.6
Depends On      : llvm-libs  gcc  compiler-rt
Optional Deps   : openmp: OpenMP support in clang with -fopenmp
                  python: for scan-view and git-clang-format [installed]
                  llvm: referenced by some clang headers [installed]
Required By     : lldb
Optional For    : qt5-tools
Conflicts With  : clang-analyzer  clang-tools-extra
Replaces        : clang-analyzer  clang-tools-extra
Installed Size  : 168.58 MiB
Packager        : Evangelos Foutras <foutrelis@archlinux.org>
Build Date      : Thu 04 Aug 2022 02:44:58 AM WAT
Install Date    : Mon 15 Aug 2022 09:49:36 AM WAT
Install Reason  : Explicitly installed
Install Script  : No
Validated By    : Signature
```

Comment: Could be an error with the libraries. Are you using third-party libraries?

Comment: like what, all have been installed using the os package manager

Comment: Which distro are you using? Does the same happen if you try `gcc --version`? Can you compile programs without issues with `clang`? Are you using `ble.sh` or similar?

Comment: archlinux, no gcc works fine, no can't do any thing with clang, using bash

Comment: Can you run a `pacman -Qi llvm` and `pacman -Qi clang` and post the output? If there's a lot of info, just edit your post.

Comment: i ve edited the post

Comment: From what I can see, there's nothing wrong. I downloaded Arch myself; I spun it up in a VM, installed `clang`, ran `clang --version`, and everything seems to work fine. There might have been some issues with the installation, so I'd suggest uninstalling `clang` using `# pacman -Rns clang`, reboot, re-install *only* `clang` using `# pacman -S clang` and reboot again.

Answer (score 0):

Had to update all the packages, mostly had to do with some dynamic library.